# How to set nginx proxying for two different angular build

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to set up an Nginx reverse proxy for two different Angualr projects.One build is serving on 80 port and another on 2000 port.Here am added the configuration file of nginx. But the reverse proxy was not working and it always pointing to the "**location /** " rule ( ie,proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217/;)

```
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
            
    location  / {           
            proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217/;
    }                
    
    location /#/login {
            
            proxy_pass http://3.81.197.217:2000/;
   }
```

These set up are done on a proxy server and the actual code was running on another server.

Application 1 : http://3.81.197.217/#/
Application 2 : http://3.81.197.217/#/login